# How can I make Firefox word-break with CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, word-wrap

This is my code so far:

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red">
            ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
</div>
```

However,

```
word-wrap:break-word;
word-break:break-all;
```

does not prove useful, since it can't word-wrap on Firefox.
*What can I do, using CSS*?

Comment: Which version of FF are u using? http://jsfiddle.net/xUwkF/ this is working on FF 3.6

Comment: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/word-wrap/

Answer (score 57):

```
white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
width:200px;
```

The above piece of code works for me wonderfully

Comment: Why is the width critical? Is it possible to get it to use the width of the container?

Comment: it worked for me, i had to add white-space: pre-wrap !important;

Comment: Not working if the element has display:flex. It's supposed to work like that, according to the specs, they said in the bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136818

Comment: I was fussing with some cross-browser-compatible css styles for a good half-a-workday and this was the first solution that actually solved my problem.  Kudos!!

Comment: You can now use `overflow-wrap: break-word` in place of `word-wrap`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Answer (score 31):

Use the following rules together:

```
/* For Firefox */
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-break: break-all;

/* For Chrome and IE */
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: `pre-wrap` property creates extra white space on Chrome

Comment: Chrome doesn't respond to `word-wrap`, only `word-break`.

Answer (score 17):

You have to apply the below css class on div:

```
.content-div{
    word-break:break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

And add below style on table which is bind in div

```
style='table-layout:fixed;width:306px;'
```

It will work on IE7, FF 3.6 and Chrome.

Comment: @Andrej: you should provide a link - the order of answers depends on the votes or the order you selected on your own.

Comment: It worked for me, I have a class with those styles, I have added the class to p, a, div, and other tags which are inside bootstrap's 4 columns

Answer (score 11):

you use width and display properties together with word-wrap property:

```
width: 100px;
word-wrap: break-word;
display:inline-block;
```

It works for me both in IE and in FF.

Comment: for some reason, i needed the display:inline-block in FF

Comment: Why is the width critical?  Is it possible to get it to use the width of the div?

Answer (score 9):

it works this way for Firefox:

```
word-break: initial;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 7):

That work for me nicely:

```
/* For Firefox */
white-space: pre-wrap;
overflow-wrap: break-word;

/* For Chrome and IE */
word-wrap: break-word;
```

It looks overflow-wrap is something new in firefox.
More info can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: "The property was originally a nonstandard and unprefixed Microsoft extension called `word-wrap`, and was implemented by most browsers with the same name. **It has since been renamed to `overflow-wrap`, with `word-wrap` being an alias.**"

Comment: Looks like only using the section *For Firefox* works well both in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Hows about we try this:

```
div{ overflow-wrap:break-word; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed a combination of several answers to get it to work in both Chrome and Firefox for me:

```
.white-space-pre-wrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`word-break: break-word` is deprecated. You should use: 
`word-break: normal; overflow-wrap: anywhere`

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

```
  /* Mozilla fix */
  word-break: break-all;

  /* Chrome fix */
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the below styles it worked fine for me in mozilla firefox.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
display:block;
```