# How to gracefully break text in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

[image: The div cutting off long words in Firefox only]

So I have this text that needs to break if it gets too long: If there's a hyphen or space in the word it should break on that. Is there a css style that makes this happen?

The closest I've gotten is by using word-wrap:break-word, which works in Chrome, but not Firefox. This is what it looks like in FF:

[image: Awkward Break with word-wrap]

Here's other things I've tried:

Max-Width - this has worked for me in the past, but it's having no affect.

Here's how it should look, as it does in [my code on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heetertc/mwf2B/1/) or Chrome, it breaks on the hyphen:

[image: Correct Break in Fiddle]

Here's the code in fiddle:

```
<style>
    .landing-sem-left, .landing-seo-left, .specials-top-left {
        max-width: 460px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
    .landing-sem-left, .landing-sem-middle, .landing-seo-left, .landing-seo-middle, .specials-top-left, .specials-top-middle {
        padding-bottom: 23px;
    }
    .landing-sem-left, .landing-sem-right, .landing-sem-middle, .landing-seo-left, .landing-seo-right, .landing-seo-middle, .specials-top-left, .specials-top-right, .specials-top-middle {
        border: 0 none;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #view-specials .heading-holder, #view-browse .heading-holder {
        margin-bottom: 18px;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
    }
    .block, .heading-holder {
        display: block;
        max-width: 461px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    }

    #view-specials .heading-holder, #view-browse .heading-holder {
        margin-bottom: 18px;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .block, .heading-holder {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        max-width: 461px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    }

    #landing-sem-container .h1-size1, #landing-seo-container .h1-size1 {
        font-size: 30px !important;
    }
    .heading-holder .h1-size1 {
        color: #003D77;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    .heading-holder h1 span {
        border: 0 none;
        display: block;
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .heading-holder h1 span {
        color: #008CC1;
        display: block;
        font-size: 36px;
        line-height: 38px;
        margin: 0 0 -10px;
    }
    #landing-sem-container .h1-size3, #landing-seo-container .h1-size3, #specials-top-container .h1-size3 {
        font-size: 60px !important;
        line-height: 72px !important;
        max-width: 461px;
        width: auto;
    }
    .heading-holder .h1-size3 {
        color: #008CC1;
        font-size: 54px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    .heading-holder h1 span {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
</style>
<div class="landing-seo-left">

<div class="heading-holder">
    <h1>
        <span class="h1-size1">PRE-OWNED</span>
        <span class="h1-size3">
            Mercedes-Benz

        </span>

    </h1>
</div>

<div class="landing-seo-content">
    <p>

        Auto Lenders is a no-haggle, pre-owned car dealership with <a class="blue-bold-link" href="/store-locator/">5 New Jersey locations</a>. Browse our entire used Mercedes inventory below.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="landing-seo-content-smaller">
    <p>
        Our <a class="blue-bold-link" href="#">Mercedes  inventory</a> is updated often. If you don't see what you're looking for, call <strong>888-305-5968</strong> or hit ‘Subscribe to Search’ below to be notified when new matches arrive. 
    </p>
</div>

</div>
```

I'm not concerned with IE.

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/12235469/1202324

Comment: in my FF it doesnt break at all.

Comment: Been having a look at your code, but the css is quite messy and hard to follow. One thing, I think that if you do `max-width:461px;` and also tell that same element `width:100% !important;` it's the same as doing `width:461px;` and you lose the reflow feature. I might be wrong tho.

Comment: My "heretic" take on this: Only consider Chromium-based browsers as browsers. The rest is junk that do not deserve supporting. The `break-word` option should have been in the the specs 10+ years ago. And that's the least of the problems other browsers have... I am amazed that people only focus on `bad IE`. There is a whole sea of bad browsers out there and a sea of bad specs. If you want to support all browsers, I think what you have achieved if the best you can, using pure CSS. If you want more, only JS can "help".

Comment: However: One option for FF might be : `overflow-wrap:break-word;`. Try it out. ;P Of course, the container must have restrained width.

Answer (score 2):

1) You have to not only constrain the max-width but also to define the width for your .heading-holder to 100% to tell the browser to reserve this area for this element only. Otherwise the textblock below will begin to flow in the logo-free areas.

```
.block, .heading-holder {
  display: block;
  max-width: 461px;
  width:100%; /*<-- tell browser to require all the space for this element*/
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}
```

2) Then it's easy to implement a work around by splitting the logo sub-words with a div container set to display:inline-block. This will display the logo inline as long there is enough place for the element and breaks in two lines when there should be not enough place for it. Sorry for doing it the dirty inline style way but you've got the idea.:

```
<span class="h1-size3">
  Mercedes-<div style="display:inline-block;">Benz</div>            
</span>
```

**Here's the working [js-fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mwf2B/6/)**

Comment: Unfortunately, the text is from a generated source that I have no control over, it's not really feasible to change what is output in any way.

Comment: No idea ... yet. Should javascript be ok for you, there is [Hyphenator.js]http://hyphenator.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Version%202.2.0/WorkingExample.html for language specific automatic word breaks.

Answer (score 1):

What you really need to be doing is looking at responsive text in CSS3. Check out [this](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/handling-typography-responsive-design) and the [example](http://www.netmagazine.com/files/tutorials/demos/2012/04/handling-typography-for-responsive-design-/demo/demo.html) of what happens when you resize the page. This is the best solution to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has to do with my question. I'm trying to figure out why firefox decides to break this in the middle of a word, and not at the hyphen like Chrome does. We have a mobile site that is different than this, and that can scale and all that good stuff like your article is about, but this is just for normal web consumption. Thanks for the article though, good read.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't on the same page. When I develop I tend to just accept browser differences and look for the best common approach.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, `white-space: normal` means that a string can be broken at any space character. But this is normally not needed, as it is the default. However, some special characters around a space may prevent normal wrapping in some browsers; it’s really a [mess](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html).

For a hyphen, there is nothing similar, but there are various other techniques. In fact, reasonably modern versions of Firefox treat a hyphen as allowing a line break after it, but only if there is a sufficient amount of letters on either side of it – and in the case of “Mercedes-Benz”, the amount of letters after the hyphen is not quite sufficient.

Probably the safest technique is to use CSS to add a ZERO-WIDTH SPACE after the hyphen. It acts as an invisible line breaking hint. The character causes some problems in old versions of IE, but they are so old that the CSS technique is safe (they ignore the CSS rule). This means that you would need markup like

```
<a class=part>Mercedes-</a>Benz
```

and CSS like

```
.part:after { content: "\200B"; }
```

Using `span` rather than `a` would be better in general, but the CSS in your fiddle would then cause some undesired side effects. You should probably tune those rules so that you can use `span` here. You could make the `span` contain just the hyphen if you like, but then it would be better to invent a better class name.

Do *not* use `word-wrap:break-word`, because it literally breaks words, instead of proper word division.