# Cell overflow issues with table CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with the following code that is giving me some trouble:

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/hF3vt/

**[Html]**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 18%;">Col 1</th>
        <th style="width: 12%;">Col 2</th>
        <th style="width: 13%;">Col 3</th>
        <th style="width: 7%">Col 4</th>
        <th style="width: 7%">Col 5</th>
        <th style="width: 6%">Col 6</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 7</th>
        <th style="width: 13%">Col 8</th>
        <th style="width: 16%">Col 9</th>
        <th style="width: 3%">Col 10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>etc</td>
        <td>whatever</td>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td>Alotofdatainthiscell</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[CSS]**

```
table {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 auto 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;

    z-index: -1;
}

td {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

As you can see by this I am trying to have the table sized dynamically according to the window until it hits 1300px and then has a set size.

Everything works fine until I have too much data in a single cell, causing it to become wider than it should for some reason. To fix this I tried to add the ellipsis overflow but that did nothing when I added it. I then remembered that max-width is needed so I added classes to each cell to match the header percent sizes in max-width but that didn't work for some reason unless I specified a max-width in pixels. I was wondering if theres a better way to prevent this ellipsis overflow thing without having to specify it on every cell, or if theres a reason that max-width doesn't work with percents.

Summary:
Long text is ignoring the width of cells and I want it to turn into ellipses when its too long but its not for some reason.

Comment: which browser ( with version ) are u looking?

Comment: though i didnt understand your question properly. Is this you want : http://jsfiddle.net/hF3vt/1/

Answer (score 0):

When you align it proper border then it will display in well manner. without border this is because you align the width to every table header and not to `<td>`.

Here is the updated fiddle:

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tX8wL/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting a width for the table and you could also use

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

Further, if you want to wrap text of an element, you have to specify the width or max-width of that element so that browsers know how to wrap the text content.

In order to prevent really long words to break out of boundaries.
And for table,

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

Hence,
Change CSS to this:

```
table {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 auto 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: -1;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
    max-width:100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

EDIT:
You may like to set overflow to `auto` to show the lot of data.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't really do anything to the long words they just stay the same :p

Comment: @lemondrop what do you want to do with long words? seeing `oerflow:hidden`, i guessed you just want to hide them.

Comment: I just want when the length of any data in a cell reaches its width for it to be cut off with ellipses, but nothing I try seems to work.

Comment: @lemondrop edited the answer, add `text-overflow:ellipsis;` to td,in my code, works for me

Comment: @optim I guess it is `word-break: break-word;`

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn no it is word-wrap, checked it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282757/how-to-make-word-break-on-firefox-using-css

Comment: Hmm, thanks @optim, obviously I have used `word-break: break-word;` and it also works. It's new here for me. Thanks again

Comment: @lemondrop it isn't working on jsfiddle, i don't know why, i checked test file on chrome. Can you please check once on chrome, and tell me if it works as you want it to.

Comment: @lemondrop `text-overflow` showing up in red-color on jsfiddle. Does it support `text-overflow`.?

Comment: Except this isnt jsfiddle its an actual webpage

Comment: @lemondrop look at the image attached with my answer? Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes that is, how did you do that without setting a max-width is the main question I guess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29897/discussion-between-optim-and-lemondrop)

Comment: @lemondrop Hey edited the answer. turns out if you want to wrap text of an element, you have to specify the width or max-width of that element so that browsers know how to wrap the text content.